# How to create a new FOSUserBundle user programatically using the same validation as on web form?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am running a `Symfony 2.8` based web app using `FOSUserBundle` to manage users. Creating new users with a web form is absolutely no problem.

Now I would like to add a feature to create new users with a REST api. Of course submitting username, password, email, etc. to a controller is no big deal:

```
public function registerAction(Request $request) {    
    $requestJson = json_decode($request->getContent(), true); 

    $username = $requestJson[JSON_KEY_USERNAME];
    $email    = $requestJson[JSON_KEY_MAIL];
    $password = $requestJson[JSON_KEY_PASSWORD];
    ...

    $this->registerUser($username, $email, $password);

    ...
}

private function registerUser($username, $email, $password, $locale, $timezone, $currency) {
    $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');

    $emailExist = $userManager->findUserByEmail($email);
    $userNameExists = $userManager->findUserByUsername($username);

    if ($emailExist || $userNameExists)
        return false;

    $user = $userManager->createUser();

    $user->setUsername($username);
    $user->setEmail($email);
    $user->setPlainPassword($password);
    ...

    $user->setLocked(0); 
    $user->setEnabled(0); 

    $userManager->updateUser($user);

    return true;
}
```

**However, this performs no validation at all.** If for example the username is empty an `NotNullConstraintViolationException` is thrown when persisting the user object.

Of course I could manually re-implement the same validation process which is used by the RegistrationForm (username not empty, not taken, no invalid characters, password min length, e-mail format, etc.) and pass back the same error messages but this would mean to reinvent the wheel.

**Is it somehow possible to run the exact same validation which is used by the RegistrationForm?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symfony validator can work independently. In a controller you can use validator service like this:

```
$violations = $this->get('validator')->validate($user, null, ['your_groups_here']);
// Or inject Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface into a service.
```

It will return a [ConstraintViolationListInterface](https://github.com/symfony/validator/blob/master/ConstraintViolationListInterface.php), you can loop trough this object.

You can check FOSUserBundle validation groups here: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/validation.xml